# como iterar un objeto en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hice esta función:

```
const obj = [{id: 'a', time: 1}, {id: 'a', time: 2}, {id: 'b', time: 1}];

const objMapped = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let { id, time } = item;
  acc[id] = acc[id] || [];
  acc[id].push(time);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(objMapped);
```

Pero no puedo iterarlo ya que no es un `Array`, en realidad es un `Objeto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los Objetos de JavaScript tienen un método [keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) el cual devuelve un `Array` con las propiedades enumerables del mismo:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  let value = obj[key]
})
```